Mock testing in Python shows an error "no module found named path.csv"
class TestFilterDF(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('plugins.qa_plugins.preprocessing.read_df')
    def test_filter_df(self, read_df_mock):
        # Mocking read_df function to return a DataFrame directly
        read_df_mock.return_value = pd.DataFrame({
            'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
            'B': [5, 6, 7, 8],
            'C': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w']
        })

        # Mocking save_output_to_file decorator
        save_output_to_file_mock = Mock()
        expected_df = pd.DataFrame({
            'A': [3],
            'B': [7],
            'C': ['z']
        })
        save_output_to_file_mock.return_value = expected_df

        result_df, kwargs = pr.filter_df("dummy_path.csv", [
            {'column': 'A', 'condition': '> 2'},
            {'column': 'C', 'condition': "== 'z'"}
        ])

        # Asserting the output
        read_df_mock.assert_called_with("dummy_path.csv", INPUT_FILE_EXT)

        pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(result_df, expected_df)

        # Asserting the kwargs
        self.assertEqual(kwargs, {})

        # Asserting the calls to functions
        read_df_mock.assert_called_once_with("dummy_path.csv", INPUT_FILE_EXT)
        save_output_to_file_mock.assert_not_called()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

I want to mock the read_df function which takes filename as one of the arguments. I have written this code but it is showing this error:

No Module found named dummy_path.csv. save_output_to_file is a decorator which helps read_df


If you have control over filter_df, I would refactor so that it takes a file-like object, not the name of a file to open, as its argument. Then you simply pass something like a StringIO object instead of having to fuss around patching read_df.

save_output_to_file_mock isn't being used at all. I suspect you are missing a patch for that, but again, if you can provide a file-like object for filter_df to write to, instead of only providing the name of a file for it to open, that makes it easier to test.

No, I cannot change the filer_df
